# I have a port issue in tomcat7 server Running war on http://localhost:8080/ but actual port is 8090 using maven project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a port issue in tomcat7 server Running war on http://localhost:8080/ but actual port is 8090.

I am a beginner in Maven.

I have attached the error image [Port Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBwo.jpg)

```
Creating Tomcat server configuration at D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\runner\target\tomcat
[INFO] setting SystemProperties:
[INFO]  solr.solr.home=D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi/alf_data_dev/solr4/config
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: 
[INFO] Deploying dependency wars
[INFO] Deploy warfile: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\repo\target\repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to contextPath: /alfresco
[INFO] Deploy warfile: D:\Selva Kumar G\eclipse_workspace\DigGovi\share\target\share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to contextPath: /share
[INFO] Deploy warfile: C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\alfresco-solr4\5.1.e\alfresco-solr4-5.1.e.war to contextPath: /solr4
[INFO] Deploy warfile: C:\Users\B5451\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\api-explorer\1.0\api-explorer-1.0.war to contextPath: /api-explorer
```

**SETTINGS.XML**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
</settings>
```

Comment: `but actual port is 8090` ... how have you determined that the actual port is 8090?  Did you open a connector to that port in your Tomcat `server.conf` file?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - when i was installed tomcat second time i set to http/1.1 number to '8090', Yes i opened a server.xml file changed to "8090"

Comment: Can you edit your question, remove the bottom paragraph, and instead include the relevant stack trace of what happens when you try to hit your webapp on port 8090?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen   I already added the Error Log above paragraph the name is PORT ERROR

Comment: That's a link, is not an error log (it's a Maven compile time build log), and your question is not complete, because you haven't shown us the exact problem.

Comment: I think your are running this using maven and have configured your maven profile to run it at port 8080.  This will override the tomcat installation config.  Could you share your maven config?

Comment: @tom i added the maven config file

Answer (score 0):

To see the port numbers, just double click on the server in your eclipse IDE, and you will get a window of server. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgYj.png) to see the sample of server window. 
In this HTTP/1.1 is the port you are using on your Url with localhost.

If you are **not using eclipse IDE**, then open your apache tomcat server folder in your local disk. Go to ***conf*** folder. Inside ***conf*** you will find a file called ***server***. In that XML file You can see a portion [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpR84.png). This is your port number.